# Replicating mousemove() event for tablet and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, tablet

I am trying to recreate a piece of code that has been written for desktop, so that on `mousemove`, the menu displays.

This doesn't work on iPad / mobile, so I am trying to convert it to be the same event on tap, but how to make it work?

Code for desktop:

```
$(function() {
$("body").mousemove(function () {
    /* specify the time in milliseconds */
    /* 100 = fast fade-in, 1000 = slow fade-in */
    $("#fader").fadeIn(500);  
});
    }
```

Code I am working on for mobile / tablet, which is currently not working:

```
$("body").on({ 'tap' : function(){   
    $("#fader").fadeIn(500);  } });
});
    }
```

Comment: have you tried ``mousedown``?

Answer (score 3):

If there was a `tap` event, you could simply do the following:

```
$("body").on('tap', function(){
  $("#fader").fadeIn(500);
});
```

but as jQuery touch events are not recognized by jQuery core, you would have to use a library like the mighty [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) (on [GitHub](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js)) for that:

Just include the library after jquery and before calling your code and the code above should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.hammer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, just downloaded that and added the script in. Will the same piece of code work with that?

Comment: not the mousemove part, but you can now listen to events like `tap` etc

Comment: Ok thanks, just downloaded that and added the script in. I have amended the code to that below following what i could find on hammer.js but still no joy... any idea why?

var element = document.getElementById('body');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function() {   
 $("#fader").fadeIn(500);  } });
});
 }

Comment: you have more closing braces than opening. Did you check your browsers console for errros ?

Comment: Right I solved it using the following code, if anyone is having the same trouble: 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById('container');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
         $("#fader").fadeIn(500);
    });
</script>

Thanks for the help everyone, have voted up your comment.